# How to reduce the turbulence of a robotic arm, when it's end effector touches a surface?

Tags: control, robotic-arm, kinematics, dynamics, bullet

I am working on a project related to tele-robotic ultrasound where I have to tele-operate a virtual UR5 robotic arm with a end-effector(a thin rod) through a haptic device in PyBullet. When I make the arm to touch a surface say a table then as the rod gets in contact it starts to oscillate where as when we move the arm along the free space without any contact then it's working fine(it follows the haptic device well).

Motion mapping between haptic device and UR5 is achieved by mapping the joint states of Haptic Device to that of UR5 and with position control, UR5 is made to reach the particular joint state.

(Simulation Setup in PyBullet)

[image: Simulation Setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stiff robot arm, in contact with a stiff environment, will yield very high contact forces and an instable contact.

For a stable contact, you need some compliance in either your tool or your object.

Comment: Yeah you're right actually contact forces are really high. What do you mean by "compliance" exactly ? Is it something like the object should have some contact parameters/friction ? If so then at the end of rod there's actually a small sphere with those properties defined which actually makes the contact.

Comment: 'Compliance' is 'elasticity' or 'flexibility', i.e. the opposite of stiffness.

Comment: Then modelling either one as soft body will make the simulations complex i.e slower.

Comment: These links seem relevant: 
https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/issues/2422
https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/issues/2422

From [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=pybullet+stiff+contact)